# How sending emails to users authorised to view a post - polymorphic association Ruby-on-Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mvcmailer

Using polymorphic association, I was able to give specific users access to edit a particular post.

My model looks like this

User model

```
has_many :postuser
has_many :posts, through: :postuser
```

Post model

```
has_many :postuser
has_many :users, through: :postuser
```

post user

```
belongs_to :post
belongs_to :user
```

I want to send all users authorised to view a post whenever the post is updated.

In my model_mailer I have

```
class ModelMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def new_user_notification(post)
    @post = post
    mail to: @Post.postuser.user.email, subject: "Welcome User"
  end
end
```

but I am getting

```
undefined method `postuser'
```

how do I send mails to only users related via postusers.

Comment: As an aside: `has_many :postusers`

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: postuser is singular, as @benjessop has pointed out, you probably want to change the has_many to `:postusers`.  And change it everywhere else.

Comment: As @benjessop mentioned , it should be `has_many :postures` in both the cases in user model and in post model. As post has many postusers. When you will call `@post.postusers` you will get an array of all postures. So you have to loop through the postures to get individual user 

` postusers = @post.postusers` then you can loop through postures

Comment: is your model's name `PostUser` or `Postuser` ?

Comment: Postuser @RocKhalil

Comment: Thank you Syed, I will change it all to post users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to send email once a post is updated, you can simply do something like this.

```
def new_record_notification(post, current_user_email)
  @post = post
  @current_user_email = current_user_email  
  users_email = post.postusers.map{|post| post.user.email}.join(",")
  mail to: users_email, subject: "Your post has been updated"
end
```

and then you can have this in your update method in the post controller

```
ModelMailer.new_record_notification(@project, current_user.email).deliver_now
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick fix:

user.rb

```
has_many :postusers
has_many :posts, through: :postusers
```

post.rb

```
has_many :postusers
has_many :users, through: :postuser
```

postuser.rb

```
belongs_to :post
belongs_to :user

after_commit -> {
  ModelMailer.new_user_notification(post, user).deliver_now # or deliver_later
}, on: :create
```

model_mailer.rb

```
class ModelMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def new_user_notification(post, user)
    @post = post
    mail to: user.email, subject: "Welcome User"
  end
end
```

Now, whenever you create a new postuser, the after_create trigger will run and will send the email for your user.

I also suggest that you change your model to `PostUser` and use `post_users` which is the `rails` way.

```
rails g model post_user post:references user:references
```